# How to remove Java unlimited Strength Policy files?

Tags: java, cryptography, aes, jce

I've installed the unlimited Java policy files. I've installed it in `JavaHome/jre/lib/security` and `JavaHome/jdk/jre/lib/security`.

Now when I run a program and check the maximum key size allowed after the installation of these files it throws an error.

I don't think installing the files in the jdk directory is a problem as I've been running Java in Eclipse for a week and everything else ran fine (AES 128-bit programs) but when I figured out how to properly install the files I installed the files in the `/jre` directory . The moment I did that and ran the same program with AES128-bit encryption I got an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HfB9.png)

Is there a possible way to fix this problem?

What could possibly be the cause of this error?

Comment: If you haven't saved a copy of the original files, then you will need to reinstall the JRE or JDK. Make sure you installed the **right** unlimited strength policy files (those for Java 8).

Comment: Java 8 link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html download it again and replace jars.

Comment: where am i supposed to be installing in the **jdk/jre** directory or the **jre**

Comment: @Dhruva The one you plan to be using. As you installed both, you should replace them in both.